# Dereferencing Perl hashrefs

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

Using [`Text::Ngram`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aNgram) I have

```
my $c = ngram_counts($text, 3);
my %ct = %($c);
```

which doesn't work (`Scalar found where operator expected`).  I think this is a combination of not knowing what I'm doing (still not very good with Perl) and being confused about what exactly I'm getting as output from Text::Ngram.  Help?  I just want to look at the generated n-grams:

```
my @keys = sort {$ct{$a} cmp $ct{$b} } keys %ct;
foreach my $k (@keys) {
    print "$k: $ct{$k}\n"
}
```

Edit: Stupid error on my part, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use curly braces to dereference the hash reference:

```
my %ct = %{ $ct };  # %$ct would also work
```

And you probably want to use `<=>` for numerical sorting instead of the ASCII-betical sorting `cmp`.

Answer (score 7):

Use curly braces:

```
my %ct = %{ $c };
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to make a copy into another hash, just use the reference.

```
my $c = ngram_counts($text, 3);

my @keys = sort {$c->{$a} <=> $c->{$b} } keys %$c;
foreach my $k (@keys) {
    print "$k: $c->{$k}\n"
}
```

See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference for some easy to remember rules for dealing with references.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this?

```
my $c = ngram_counts({}, $text, 3);
```